# grails ant task, set different envrionment

Tags: grails, ant

Trying to create a grails ant task that has other environments besides prod for the war task.

i've tried

```
<target name="war" depends="-init-grails" description="--> Creates a WAR of a Grails application">
        <grails script="War" args="grails.env=${env} ${war.filename}"/>
</target>
```

and

```
<target name="war" depends="-init-grails" description="--> Creates a WAR of a Grails application">
        <grails script="War" args="-Dgrails.env=${env} ${war.filename}"/>
</target>
```

Neither of these two work and always just run the production env. Note that I've also hard coded ${env} so it's not that it's missing

Comment: i should note that whatever the solution it needs to work via cmd line and in eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a macrodef for this:

```
<property environment='env'/>

<property name='grails.home' value='${env.GRAILS_HOME}' />

<condition property='grails' value='grails.bat'>
   <os family='windows'/>
</condition>
<property name='grails' value='grails' />

<macrodef name='grails'>
   <attribute name='action' />
   <attribute name='environment' default='dev' />
   <element name='preargs' optional='true' />
   <element name='args' optional='true' />
   <sequential>
      <exec executable='${grails}' failonerror='true'>
         <preargs />
         <arg value='@{environment}'/>
         <arg value='@{action}'/>
         <args />
      </exec>
   </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

You can execute simple commands:

```
<grails action='clean' />
```

or more complex ones like your war task:

```
<grails action='war' environment='${env}'>
   <args>
      <arg value="${war.filename}" />
   </args>
</grails>
```

Comment: Hey burt! This still doesn't let me use the grails built in ant tasks with other environments than prod. If it's a bug it should be reported if not then I'd like to know how to do it. But I do like your macro. Might end up going that route if nothing else works.

Comment: That's weird - I tested this with the above macrodef, condition and property declarations and these targets and it created a war called test.war using the test env:

    <target name='-init-grails'>
       <property name='env' value='test'/>
       <property name='war.filename' value='test.war'/>
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="-init-grails">
       <grails action='war' environment='${env}'>
          <args>
             <arg value="${war.filename}" />
          </args>
       </grails>
    </target>

Comment: I know the macrodef will work. I was trying to get the built in antTask that's in the grails bootstrap to work without having to fall back to exec

Comment: It seems that i might have to put the full path to the executable because eclipse (STS) can't find "grails"

Comment: only change I had to make was moving from 
<arg value='@{environment}'/> to <arg value='-Dgrails.env=@{environment}'/> to be able to pass in my custom envrionments

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at grails scripting to solve your problem

http://www.grails.org/Command+Line+Scripting

it has wrapped ANT so you can utilize ant tasks inside the scripts and I believe you have access to the environment and lots of other "groovy" stuff

i think you can also do  this if you are set on using ant, although I havent tried it with grails scripts

```
<exec executable="grails"  failonerror="true">
    <arg line='-c war grails.env=${env} ${war.filename}' />
</exec>
```

Comment: I've thought of using exec but it has to stay in ant rather than gant since it's part of a much larger j2ee app. We're trying to war the grails project up and include it in a larger .ear which is working great accept for the environment

Comment: ended up having to go with exec like you said since the official grails ant task doesn't seem to support the custom env's or anything else but prod from what I can see

Answer (score 0):

if you go in your project directory and run "grails --integrate-with -ant" it will create a build.xml which will automatically use ivy to download dependencies, and grails, and creates the macro def for you.

You can use the build.xml as a starting point for your project

Comment: I assume this is new since this ? was asked.  No longer an issue

Comment: I wanted to add this info for people googling this problem - using the auto-generated build.xml is much less daunting to a new user than copying and modifying macro defs if they're new to ant