# Unable to Start Grails using ant

Tags: grails, ant, build

I'm cutting over a project from grails 1.3.6 to grails 2.2.4.  The project is built on an independent build VM and uses ant 1.7.1.  System variables are set to point to ant 1.7.1 and grails 2.2.4.  Grails 2.2.4 starts up successfully using the windows command line.  This is the excerpt from the ant script that should be compiling the grails file:

Task set up-

```
<path id="grails.classpath">
  <fileset dir="${env.grails.home}/dist" includes="grails-bootstrap-*.jar"/>
  <fileset dir="${env.grails.home}/lib">
    <include name="**/groovy-all*.jar"/>
    <include name="**/ivy*.jar"/>
    <include name="**/gpars*.jar"/>
    <include name="**/gant_groovy*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="grails" classname="grails.ant.GrailsTask"   classpathref="grails.classpath"/>
```

Init execution:

```
<target name="-init">
  <record name="C:/log/compile_output.log" />
  <echo level="verbose">Deleting old compiled binaries, if existing...</echo>
  <delete dir="${dir.binaries}" failonerror="false" includeemptydirs="true"/>
  <delete dir="${dir.testBinaries}" failonerror="false" includeemptydirs="true"/>
  <grails home="${env.grails.home}" script="Clean"/>  ####THIS LINE IS FAILING
  <delete dir="${dir.dist}" failonerror="false" includeemptydirs="true"/>
  <echo level="verbose">Creating directories for the compiled binaries - '${dir.binaries}' and '${dir.testBinaries}' ...</echo>
  <mkdir dir="${dir.binaries}"/>
  <mkdir dir="${dir.testBinaries}"/>
  <mkdir dir="${dir.dist}"/>
  <grails home="${env.grails.home}" script="AddProxy" args="myProxy --host=webproxy.int.westgroup.com --port=80"/>
  <grails home="${env.grails.home}" script="SetProxy" args="myProxy"/>
</target>
```

The line `<grails home="${env.grails.home}" script="Clean"/>` is failing.  The stack trace being spit out is the following:

```
D:\Builds\141\Cobalt PAC\PAC\Sources\ant\CompileAntScript.xml:72: Unable to star
t Grails: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at grails.ant.GrailsTask.runGrails(GrailsTask.java:137)
    at grails.ant.GrailsTask.execute(GrailsTask.java:98)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
 ...............
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/CompletionHandler
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.<init>(GrailsScript
Runner.java:96)
```

I've also made sure that the grails environment is set correctly. Using debug output, I see that the line `Setting project property: env.grails.home -> C:\grails-2.2.4`. Is there a conflict with such an old ant version?

----Edit-----

I created a new grails project and ran the same commands on this on my machine.  I get the exact same issue, so I am guessing it isn't a dirty cache issue.  I also tried ant 1.8.2 on the build server and received the same problem.

Looks to be related to [JIRA 8496](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8496?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issues using a very simple ant configuration drawing upon the javadoc information from `GrailsTask`.  In the end, I integrated ant (version 1.8.4) with grails (version 2.3.7) by creating a macro for grails as described by [Burt Beckwith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613700/225217).

Example:

```
<target name="init-grails">
  <property environment='env'/>
  <property name='grails.home' value='${env.GRAILS_HOME}' />
  <property name='grails.bin' value='${grails.home}/bin' />
  <condition property='grails' value='${grails.bin}/grails.bat'><os family='windows'/></condition>
  <property name='grails' value='${grails.bin}/grails' />

  <macrodef name='grails'>
    <attribute name='action' />
    <attribute name='environment' default='dev' />
    <element name='preargs' optional='true' />
    <element name='args' optional='true' />
    <sequential>
       <exec executable='${grails}' failonerror='true'>
          <preargs />
          <arg value='@{environment}'/>
          <arg value='@{action}'/>
          <args />
       </exec>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="init-grails">
  <grails action="clean"/>
</target>
```